# Proteus 8 component package error message

Tags: proteus

i built an H-Bridge circuit using proteus 8 professional and  [image]

am having this error below and i don't know how to fix it please help me out and i don't know if those are the right connectors.
[image]

Comment: You have specified PCB packages (footprints) MOL_08_ST  for component J1, and MOL_03_ST for J2, and J3, but those packages do not exist in the available libraries.  You will have to create footprints with those names, or choose footprints that do exist in the libraries (and that you can buy parts for!)

Answer (score 1):

The error messages seem quite straightforward. They say that when you added those connectors J1, J2, and J3, you specified (or left as a default?) a package type "MOL_xx_ST that is not found in the software library of Proteus 8.

You can fix this by either:

1. Changing the package type to something that is in your library
2. Adding the "MOL_xx_ST" packages to your library.  ("xx" is the number of pins)

Comment: Feel free to up-vote and "accept" the answer.  I changed the title since this question has nothing to do with "H-bridge" and everything to do with Proteus CAD.